# Qual a origem de "bué"?

Tags: etimologia, origem-histórica, sintaxe

Quando eu era mais novo, a palavra ***bué*** (*pt-PT*) era usada na expressão *bué (de) ...*, significando “muito...” Era apenas uma moda, usada em círculos informais, mas a palavra continuou a ser muito usada. Mais recentemente, penso até que entrou no dicionário com este significado.

Qual a origem da palavra *bué*? Qual foi a base ou a inspiração para a palavra? E o uso correto é com ou sem *de*?

Comment: Nunca ouvi tal expressão em pt-BR!

Comment: @gmauch, o autor abriu uma pergunta sobre se a palavra pode ser usada no Brasil: [“bué”: significados em pt-PT e pt-BR](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/bu%c3%a9-significados-em-pt-pt-e-pt-br)

Comment: @bandrade Adicionei os *bués* mais antigos do Google books. O diionário Houaiss apresenta *bué* sem preposição.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Bué***, no sentido de *muito* é de origem santomense ou, mais provavelmente, angolana. A partir daqui cada dicionário diz a sua coisa. O Dicionário da Academia das Ciências de Lisboa diz que o termo é santomense e angolano e de origem obscura. O [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bu%C3%A9) diz que vem provavelmente do [quimbundo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kimbundu), uma língua angolana. A [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/bu%C3%A9) diz que vem mesmo do quimbundo *mbewe*, que significa *abundância, fartura*.
Segundo o [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-de-origem-africana-na-lingua-portuguesa/5426) é apenas com este significado, *abundância, grande quantidade* que a palavra é usada em Angola. Daí a preposição *de*:

> Tenho *bué de* coisas para te contar. Estava lá *bué de* gente.

Mas em Portugal a palavra começou a ser usada também como advérbio, com o significado de *em elevado grau*, tornando-se *bué* completamente sinónimo de *muito*. Daí que para intensificar um adjetivo, a malta por vezes, muito naturalmente, omita a preposição, ouvindo-se quer *bué bom* quer *bué de bom* (muito frequentemente *bué da bom*). Para intensificar um verbo, naturalmente não leva preposição:

> A festa foi bué divertida. Estava lá gente bué da fixe. Curti bué.

Segundo o mesmo artigo do [Ciberdúvidas](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/palavras-de-origem-africana-na-lingua-portuguesa/5426), o uso adverbial de *bué*  está errado. Mas não me parece que isso vá impedir o pessoal de continuar a falar assim, e só o tempo é que vai decidir se a preposição antes do adjetivo (ou mesmo antes do substantivo) fica ou não. Aliás o [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/bu%C3%A9) e o Houaiss apresentam *bué* como advérbio e pronome indefinido, o que legitima (ou meramente descreve) o uso sem preposição (*estava bué gente* e *corremos bué* são os exemplos do Priberam).

E parece mesmo que o pessoal em Portugal tende a omitir a preposição, mesmo com substantivo. ***Bué de*** só supera ***bué*** sem preposição com *coisas*. Note-se que ***bué de coisas*** inclui muitos resultados de Angola, ao passo que os restantes não incluem: em Angola *bué* não intensifica adjetivos, e aparentemente por lá não se usa muito *cenas* (*coisas, situações* em Portugal).

**Milhares de resultados no Google search de *bué fixe, bué de fixe, bué giro*, etc.**

```
            Fixe        Giro       Cenas      Coisas
Bué        111,0        18,8        6,2        2,5
Bué de       6,1         3,2        3,2        3,5
Bué da      18,7         2,3        1,0        0,5
```

O dicionário Houaiss diz que *bué* é usado na [Estremadura (região que inclui Lisboa)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Estremadura) desde cerca de 1970, e não faz referência a Angola. A ocorrência mais antiga o Artefacto encontrou no Google Books é de 1979 ou 1980, e têm quase de certeza origem africana (ênfase minha):

> Posso pensar um significado na língua em que me expresso e escolher de entre as línguas nossas o significante mais calhado para a minha oficina. Por exemplo: ***bué*** de maravilha é-me mais calhado, é-me mais bonito que muita maravilha. [[*África*, nº 5-8, África Editora, 1979.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MMAbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bu%C3%A9%20de%20maravilha%22&dq=%22bu%C3%A9%20de%20maravilha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj95ob8g9jMAhUFvxQKHTJPDk0Q6AEIGzAA)

Depois temos dois exemplos de Agola dos anos oitenta:

> Aqui fora, escuro! Escuríssimo! Deixa mano, hum! ***Bué*** de verdade! [[Jorge Macedo, *Geografia da Coragem*, Ediciones Cubanas para a União dos Escritores Angolanos, 1985.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=t_UeAQAAIAAJ&q=%22Bu%C3%A9%20de%20verdade%22&dq=%22Bu%C3%A9%20de%20verdade%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZk4S3rdfMAhXCWxQKHQSYD0cQ6AEIGzAA)
>
> […] ministro não manda comprar os porcos das províncias e pôr nas bichas de Luanda? Matadouro o tuga deixou. Vejam só: um povo revolucionário como o de Cuba tem a mesma opinião, come ***bué*** de carne de porco [[Estudos portugueses e africanos, n. 9-12, Universidade Estadual de Campinas, 1987]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=MBBXAAAAYAAJ&q=%22come%20bu%C3%A9%20da%20carne%22&dq=%22come%20bu%C3%A9%20da%20carne%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwimuv_Pq9fMAhVG6RQKHUhSDUwQ6AEIGzAA)

Depois encontram-se duas de origem portuguesa de 1993 (*um coche* significa “um pouco”; negritos meus, itálicos originais):

> Dá para ver *cenas **bué** d’speedadas* [muito agitadas], grande *curtição* […] trabalhar e não voltasse à escola, não sei… acho que ia custar um *coche*, um *coche* não, ia custar ***bué*** [[José Machado Pais, *Culturas Juvenis*, 1993.]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=dDCsAAAAIAAJ&q=bu%C3%A9%20muito&dq=bu%C3%A9%20muito&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjT1pLtm9fMAhXHfRoKHZICAz44ChDoAQg6MAQ)

A outra ocorrência de 1993 é do célebre [*Dicionário de Português Schifaizfavoire, Crônicas Lusitanas* de Mário Prata](http://www.dartmouth.edu/%7Emavall/libguides/documents/Schifaizfavoire.pdf). O autor brasileiro andou por Portugal e registou o uso:

> **Bué**
> Gíria da malta bem jovem. Para eles tudo é bué de caro, bué de longe. Ou seja, *muito* caro, *muito* longe. A origem é angolana.

Comment: Este aqui é de 1979, a julgar pelo Google Books: https://books.google.pt/books?id=MMAbAQAAMAAJ&q=%22bu%C3%A9+de+maravilha%22&dq=%22bu%C3%A9+de+maravilha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj95ob8g9jMAhUFvxQKHTJPDk0Q6AEIGzAA

Comment: Dependendo do número, pode ser [1979](http://aleph18.sibul.ul.pt/F/SEPU2591BYBX38VDI9R6J5S4A8N99MPLVVV8DSLCH96QNUP1MP-49903?func=item-global&doc_library=ULB01&doc_number=000094387&year=1979&volume=&sub_library=) ou 1980 (o Google só diz _Issues 5-8). Em todo o caso, parece claro que vem de uma língua nativa de Angola.

Comment: @Artefacto Obrigado, não sei como é que esse me escapou.