# "bué": significados em pt-PT e pt-BR

Tags: diferenças-transatlânticas

Em Portugal, a palavra **bué** é usada como quantificador, de forma informal:

- "bué (de) coisas" = "muitas coisas"
- "bué (de) gente" = "muita gente"

Esta palavra pode ser usada com o mesmo significado no Brasil?

Comment: Como falante nativo de pt-BR nunca ouvi ou li esta expressão (à 1a vista me parece a onomatopéia do choro de uma criança), mas isso não é impedimento suficiente para que não a uses no Brasil!

Comment: Tem uma definição [bué](http://www.priberam.pt/DLPO/bu%C3%A9) interessante.

Comment: @gmauch O [Aulete regista *bué*](http://www.aulete.com.br/bu%C3%A9) como *choradeira de criança*, e aí a origem é quase de certeza onomatopeica. O *bué* de Portugal e Angola tem origem diferente.

Comment: Também não tenho conhecimento da expressão aqui no Brasil, seja de forma escrita ou por pessoas falando com exceção de um "choro de criança", como já mencionado, pois a pronúncia de bué é parecida ao som de um bebê chorando

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Desejando contribuir para o esclarecimento desta questão, a saber, se *bué* é ou não usado no Brasil, e faltando-me a experiência pessoal, resta-me a abordagem *científica*.

**MÉTODO**

Utilizaremos o Goodle search. Adotaremos uma *ignorância metodológica* acerca de ser ou não *bué* usado no Brasil. Para decidir se uma ocorrência de *bué* é de origem lusa ou brasileira, utilizaremos como *proxies* as palavras *fixe* e *legal*, que significam *bom* em Portugal e no Brasil respetivamente. Como está amplamente demonstrado, *fixe* é um lusitanismo não usado no Brasil ([O que é e como se pronuncia fixe?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/85/o-que-%C3%A9-e-como-se-pronuncia-fixe), [Why is «fixe» a cool thing in Portugal?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1328/why-is-fixe-a-cool-thing-in-portugal)). Logo qualquer *bué fixe* ou *bué da fixe* terá origem portuguesa. *Legal* significa *bom* no Brasil. Em Portugal significa apenas *de acordo com a lei*. Logo qualquer *bué legal* terá origem brasileira, pois ninguém diz *bué de acordo com a lei*. Para controlo e teste estatístico observaremos também as expressões *bem legal, muito legal, bem fixe* e *muito fixe*.

**RESULTADOS**

Os resultados, em milhares de ocorrências, estão indicados na tabela abaixo. «Bué» inclui «bué de» e «bué da»; «muito» inclui «muita».

```
               Fixe             Legal
Bué             137                0,5
Bem              65             1250
Muito           404            11310
Total           606            12560,5
Bué/Total      22,6%           0,004%
```

Como se pode ver *legal* é extremamente comum, mas raramente aparece associado a *bué*. Se *bué* fosse usado no Brasil observar-se-iam muito mais ocorrências de *bué legal*. As raras ocorrências de *bué legal* não são mais do que as esperáveis do cruzamento de culturas, portugueses a viver no Brasil ou brasileiros a viver em Portugal.

**CONCLUSÃO**

*Bué* não é usado no Brasil como intensificador de adjetivos. Caberá a pesquisa futura averiguar se é usado com substantivos para indicar abundância.

Comment: Excelente resposta Jacinto.

Comment: Obrigado. Já me estava estava a fazer comichão ver esta pergunta aqui há tanto tempo sem resposta.

Comment: Muito bem! À falta de conhecimento de causa direto, foi sem dúvida um excelente raciocínio!